# UITableView layer shadow performance optimisation?

Tags: performance, uitableview, calayer, shadow, rasterizing

I have got a `UITableView` with cells that include a layer shadow and their subviews do too. So summed up I have about 5 shadows per cell. I reuse my cells but they change their height occasionally when the content exceeds a certain height (I say this because this could probably cause more draw calls with the 'optimisations' I enlist below).

Now, I have added the following optimisations:

```
// setting it opaque will tell the GPU not to blend the 
// layer (-> less draw calls - only useful when layer completely opaque obviously)
myShadowView.opaque = YES;

// another significant factor was the shadowPath property, 
// it significantly smoothed scrolling
myShadowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, -1);
myShadowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.08;
myShadowView.layer.shadowRadius = 1;
myShadowView.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:shad.bounds].CGPath;

// the most important change
myShadowView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
myShadowView.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
```

I am very very happy with the performance -- scrolling is smooth as baby skin -- but the `shouldRasterize` property comes with drawbacks. When I scroll down, it takes the cell a little while to load the bitmap. Is there any way to pre-render those cells ? Would a table without the reuse identifier get rid of the problem ?

I absolutely need the shadows, but I would not sacrifice performance for them. I hope someody can help.